# Let $f_1:A \rightarrow B$, $f_2:C \rightarrow B$ functions. Prove that, if $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$ for all $x\in A\cap C$, then $f_1 \cup f_2$ is function.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I want to test the above, so my idea is as follows:

take $f=f_1 \cup f_2$ and prove that $f:A\cap C \rightarrow B$ is function.

To do this, we start with $x \in A\cap C$, then $x \in A$ and $x \in C$, therefore exists $b \in B$ such that $(x, b) \in f_1$ because $f_1$ and $f_2$ are functions in particular, if they are at the intersection they will be at the junction, whereby $(x, b) \in f_1\cup f_2$

Moreover, for $(x, b), (x, c)\in f_1\cup f_2$ then $b=c$ for $(x, b), (x, c)\in f_1$ or $(x, b), (x, c)\in  f_2$ as both are functions
That was my idea to prove that the union of those functions is function, but I'm not quite sure, any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: $f$ is not a function from $A\cap C\to B$, but from $A\cup C\to B$.

Comment: Show that $A-B$, $A \cap B$, and $B-A$ are a partition of $A \cup B$ then show that the relation is a function on all three of those subsets.